# Creating a New Cordova Android project

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I tried to create a new Cordova Android project using CLI.
- i installed cordova.
- created a new project
- Then i tried to add platform, ie android

i installed ant windows installer from this location (https://code.google.com/p/winant/)

and tried the below,

```
D:\icare>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:12
6
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.
js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node
_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\n
ode_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\
cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\
q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_mod
ules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: C:\Users\christy.r\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Com
mand failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\christy.r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I installer ant for windows, but i didnt set the environment variables(actually i dont have access to it). The above error is showing in my command prompt. can someone tell me what iam doing wrong ? or walkthrough me through the steps to install this ?

Thanks in andavce.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error days ago.
The solution is to set all the needed environment variable (if you can't you have a big problem :) ).
These are the variables:

```
JAVA_HOME eg. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
ANDROID_HOME eg. C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
ANT_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.3
```

The above are user variables. Obviously they must reflect your system.
Then you have to edit the PATH system variable and add these path if you already haven't.
Obviously you have to change these paths in order to reflect your system.

```
;C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
;C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin
```

Then restart the console window and run again the command to create the project, it should work.

Comment: i have the same problem. all paths seem correct to me and ant is installed, i can verify it. what different thing can cause the problem? do you have any other idea?

Comment: Are you sure all your paths are correct? Do you really have the liste user variables created? Did you restarted your console window (or better, your PC) if you added/edited them just now?